# i am trying to solve RSA algorithm, how i generate public key? in mathematical problem...i can't understand

Tags: cryptography

Select two prime no's. Suppose P = 53 and Q = 59.
Now First part of the Public key  : n = P*Q = 3127.

We also need a small exponent say e : 
But e Must be

An integer.

Not be a factor of n.

1 < e < Φ(n) [Φ(n) is discussed below], 
Let us now consider it to be equal to 3.

Our Public Key is made of n and e
Generating Private Key :

We need to calculate Φ(n) :
Such that Φ(n) = (P-1)(Q-1)
      so,  Φ(n) = 3016

Now calculate Private Key, d : 
d = (k*Φ(n) + 1) / e for some integer k
For k = 2, value of d is 2011.

Comment: Probably a better fit in [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), SO is about coding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about crypto, not programming.